# log4j console appender and log file size

Tags: jboss, log4j, stdout

I am using Jboss 4.0.2 in Solaris to run a webapp.

JBoss is configured to use the factory default log4j.xml file, and this has a ConsoleAppender. I am redirecting stdout of jboss java process to a file.

Something interesting happens when I try to cleanup this file - jboss.out.

This is where I start.

```
$ ls -alhrt jboss.out
-rw-r--r--   1 ipunity  ipunity     458M Jan  8 07:22 jboss.out
```

Then I clean up this file. Jboss is still running.

```
$ >jboss.out
$ ls -alhrt jboss.out
-rw-r--r--   1 ipunity  ipunity        0 Jan  8 07:24 jboss.out
```

Now if go click on a link in my webapp, it starts logging, but the whole file kind of reappears again!

```
$ ls -alhrt jboss.out
-rw-r--r--   1 ipunity  ipunity     458M Jan  8 07:25 jboss.out
```

Any ideas on whats going on?

Is ConsoleAppender buffering the data? I dont have enough memory to hold 458MB and my disk swap is almost unused. I dont see any temp file this huge either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably a sparse file, created by the OS when JBoss issues a write with the file pointer set to +[whatever the old size of the file was].

Check the disk space actually used by the new file -- on most unices, `du -k jboss.out` should work.  If the file is sparse, you should see something significantly less than the size shown by `ls`.

Generally, removing log files while they're being written to is tricky.  To avoid that issue when capturing stdout, I tend to pipe stdout to a program like [cronolog](http://cronolog.org/) or [rotatelogs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/programs/rotatelogs.html) instead of straight to a file.